# How to import database of already created project

Tags: php, html, mysqlimport

I'm trying to importing the database of already created project .the database is sucessfully imported in my system but in my friend pc instead of importing the database ,just created another copy of the database name.
i simply created database with name onlineshopping and then select it and click on import and press go .

Comment: Your question is lacking information. You should post as many informations as you have. And explicitly saying that you are using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Can you post the .sql generated when you exported the database ? if it's too long. Post as much as you can of it.

Comment: i create the database and import the database in it but when i try to import that particular database in it another  named ,database with different name is automatically created .